# cannot load a nested template .jsp file

Tags: java, css, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to make a basic template system for my Spring MVC project. I am struggling to have a dynamic navigation bar and dynamic content on the same page. When I do not have the `@RequestMapping(value = "/generic/navbar")`, I get the expected output of "loading navbar". However, all the Bootstrap CSS and JQuery is broken. Inspecting the resources in chromes shows that the Bootstrap and JQuery scripts have been replaced with the HTML code in navbar.jsp. If I keep the `@RequestMapping(value = "/generic/navbar")`, the page loads the javascript correctly, but the navbar is not loaded.

I suspect that I have messed up something pertaining to the Request, but I do not know how to fix it. Can anyone help me please?

This is my code that will load the navigation bar.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/generic/navbar") //causes problems
public class NavbarController {
    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public String renderNavbar(Map<String, Object> model) {
        System.out.println("loading navbar");
        System.out.println(model);
        return "generic/navbar";
    }
}
```

This is the associated navbar.jsp file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index">IPIMS</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="../../../"> Home </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is a page where I try to use two jsp files:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="input" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<t:userpage>
    <jsp:attribute name="nav">
        <jsp:include page="generic/navbar.jsp"/>
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="footer">
        <jsp:include page="generic/footer.jsp"/>
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body>
         HTML in here...
    </jsp:body>
</t:userpage>
```

and this is my custom tag:

```
<%@tag description="Overall Page template" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@attribute name="nav" fragment="true" %>
<%@attribute name="footer" fragment="true" %>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="nav">
    <jsp:invoke fragment="nav"/>
</div>
<div id="body">
    <jsp:doBody/>
</div>
<div id="pagefooter">
    <jsp:invoke fragment="footer"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```